# Controlling Atlas over ROS topic in python disabled?

Tags: python

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,
I updated to DRCsim 2.5 and since then Atlas doesn't respond to the python script, as described in this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.2/Atlas_control_over_ROS_topics_with_python).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2502/controlling-atlas-over-ros-topic-in-python-disabled?/) by [odedy86](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/297/odedy86/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Interesting.  I know the OSRF team typically goes through the tutorials after each new build and updates the tutorial language to support slight changes in the SDF format, or the scripts associated with the tutorials.  However, given the crunch for the DARPA Robotics Challenge event coming up, this may have fallen off the table.  Not sure what the scenario is here, but I will have a look and see if I can replicate your problem.

---

Originally posted by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) with karma: 61 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0